# Nearby culling in Three.js despite camera not being near face

Tags: three.js

I've run into an issue after switching to a logarithmic depth buffer in Three.js. Everything runs nicely except for nearby culling of the ground as described in the following photos:

[image]

[image]

As you can see, the camera is elevated above the ground significantly. The character box that is shown is about 2 units above the ground, and my camera is set up as such:

```
  var WIDTH = window.innerWidth
    , HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
  var VIEW_ANGLE = 70
    , ASPECT = WIDTH / HEIGHT
    , NEAR = 1e-6
    , FAR = 9000;
  var aspect = WIDTH / HEIGHT;
  var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(VIEW_ANGLE, ASPECT, NEAR, FAR);
  camera.rotation.order = 'YXZ';
```

So my `NEAR` parameter is nowhere near 2, the distance between the camera and the ground. You can see in the second image that I even move up the camera with my PointerLockControls and still run into the issue.

Can anyone diagnose my issue?

I also tested my issue by seeing if this bug occurred with a static camera as well. It does.

Additionally, this problem only happens with the logarithmic depth buffer, as it doesn't happen with the default depth buffer.

I have my camera as a child to a `controls` object, which is defined as follows:

```
controls = new THREE.PointerLockControls(camera);
controls.getObject().position.set(strtx, 50, strtz);
scene.add(controls.getObject());
camera.position.z += 2;
camera.position.y += .1;
```

Here's the relevant code for PointerLockControls:

```
var pitchObject, yawObject;
var v = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, -1);


THREE.PointerLockControls = function(camera){

    var scope = this;

    camera.rotation.set(0, 0, 0);

    pitchObject = new THREE.Object3D();
    pitchObject.rotation.x -= 0.3;
    pitchObject.add(camera);


    yawObject = new THREE.Object3D();
    yawObject.position.y = 10;
    yawObject.add(pitchObject);


    var PI_2 = Math.PI / 2;

    var onMouseMove = function(event){

        if (scope.enabled === false) return;

        var movementX = event.movementX || event.mozMovementX || event.webkitMovementX || 0;
        var movementY = event.movementY || event.mozMovementY || event.webkitMovementY || 0;

        yawObject.rotation.y -= movementX * 0.002;
        pitchObject.rotation.x -= movementY * 0.002;

        pitchObject.rotation.x = Math.max( - PI_2, Math.min( PI_2, pitchObject.rotation.x ) );

    };

    this.dispose = function() {

        document.removeEventListener( 'mousemove', onMouseMove, false );

    };

    document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onMouseMove, false );

    this.enabled = false;

    this.getObject = function () {

        return yawObject;

    };

    this.getDirection = function() {

        // assumes the camera itself is not rotated

        var rotation = new THREE.Euler(0, 0, 0, "YXZ");
    var direction = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, -1);

        return function() {

            rotation.set(pitchObject.rotation.x, yawObject.rotation.y, 0);
            v.copy(direction).applyEuler(rotation);

            return v;

        };

    }();

};
```

You'll also notice that it's only the ground that is being culled, not other objects

[image]

Edit:

I've whipped up an isolated environment that shows the larger issue. In the first image, I have a flat `PlaneBufferGeometry` that has 400 segments for both width and height, defined by `var g = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(380, 380, 400, 400);`. Even getting very close to the surface, no clipping is present:
[image]

However, if I provide only 1 segment, `var g = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(380, 380, 1, 1);`, the clipping is present
[image]

I'm not sure if this intended in Three.js/WebGL, but it seems that I'll need to do something to work around it.

Comment: Next time you want to change your question, just edit it. When you deleted your original question, you also deleted the comments, so I was unable to read nor reply to your response.

Comment: My apologies, I didn't realize it was possible to edit the title as well. The issue persists with the camera being static as well.

Comment: so is it an option to just make it 2 segments instead of 1?

Comment: It is, but that might not be enough even. I'll get back on my results. This only happens with logarithmic depth buffer and not linear, so do you think it could be a bug with three or webgl?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a bug, I think this is a feature of how the depthbuffer in the different settings works. [Look at this example](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_camera_logarithmicdepthbuffer.html). On the right, the depthbuffer can't make up its mind between the letters in "microscopic" and the sphere. This is because it has lower precision at very small scales and starts doing rounding that oscilates between one object and another, and favoring draw order over z-depth.

It's always a tradeoff. If you want to forgo this issue, you can try raising the scale of your scene overall, so that the 'near' of the camera will never be so close to something that it can round it off - so just work in a number range that won't be rounded in the exponential model of the logarithmic z-buffer.

Also another question - how is the blue defined, because maybe what you're seeing is not clipping from being too close, but confusion between whether blue or the ground is closer. If it's just a blue box encompassing everything, you could try making it bigger and more distant from the ground.

**EDIT**:
Okay, this looks like it should work. so I would start looking for edge cases. What can you do to change the scene so that it does work? What can you do to make other things start breaking?

- try moving the landscape far down/ far up (does the issue persist when looking up instead of down at it, does it persist even when it's unquestionably far away?)
- try rotating the landscape
- try changing the camera FOV
- try changing the camera far plane
- try changing the camera near plane from 1e-x notation to .000001, .0001,.01,.1, etc. see what effect it has.
- console.log the camera object in your render function, and make sure that the fov, near, far etc, is as you set on setup and that it's not being overwritten and reset to default. check what it prints out in chrome's developer tools, you can browse the whole object, check position, parent name, all that stuff.

basically i don't see a blatant mistake, so I would guess it's something hard to spot, or it's working exactly as it should. Figure out what you can do to improve the effect/ make it worse, and that will clarify a direction to go.

A good rule of thumb for debugging is to try and just take things to an extreme, without trying to fix it, or keep the code true to its purpose, and just see in what way it breaks further/changes. report back when you find something.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The blue is actually just the background, not a box, so that isn't the issue. As for the scale of my scene, it seems like it's quite large, as the character that you see is 2 units in height.

Comment: show the section where you define your cameras position and insert it into the scane. I see where you define your FOV, but is it the child or something with any scale on it? Does it get moved dynamically?

Comment: I've modified my question to contain controls and camera parent.

Comment: Thanks again for your efforts! I'll keep at the issue and report my findings.

Comment: I've updated my question with some interesting findings.